# How to do something BEFORE a view is updated via ajax submit button?

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have a view with exposed filters and Ajax activated.
I would like to validate my exposed filters values before my view is updated by the submit button.
The following code works without Ajax, but when I activate this functionalitty it doesn't validate!

```
jQuery('FORM ID').submit(function () {
  jQuery('FILTER TEXTFIELD').val(MY VALIDATION);
  return true;
});
```

How can i capture the ajax execution and validate my values BEFORE the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the mousedown event on the submit / apply button, prevent submission using e.preventDefault(), validate and if everything is fine submit the form using $('#form-id').submit()

**Update:**

Here is a fully tested and working code:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ValidateAjaxForm = {
        attach : function (context, settings) {

            var $form = $("form#views-exposed-form-list", context); // ajax form selector, or better specify by class name
            var $submitButton = $('#edit-submit-list', $form); // ajax submit button selector, or better specify by class name

            // Use off to remove any existing submit handler
            $form
            .off('submit')
            .on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $(this);

                var valid = false;

                // Run some validation on $form object.
                // check conditions here and if all is fine declare valid = true

                // If vaild, trigger event on button
                if (valid) {
                    $form[0].submit();
                }

            });
        }
    };
}
    (jQuery));
```

Comment: Still not working when Ajax is turned on

Comment: @xstean kindly see my newest answer. Sorry I did not paid attention at first that ajax is enabled on the view.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make validation work in case *ajax is enabled*, do the following:

1) You have to apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1907932#comment-8817409) to */misc/ajax.js* .. (should be committed to core in near future I expect)

2) Use this code to capture the submit event and to do validation before actual form submission:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ValidateAjaxForm = {
        attach : function (context, settings) {

            Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {

                // First make sure that the Ajax event is triggered by the form to be validated
                if ($(element.context).is($("form#views-exposed-form-ID"))) { // relpace with form id

                    var isValid = true;

                    // Do validation work here
                    // if anything is wrong decalre isValid = false

                    return isValid;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
    (jQuery));
```